# how can i place master page inside from tag with runat server

Tags: c#-3.0

Control 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvTransDetails' of type 'GridView' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server

how can i place master page inside from tag with runat server

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting this message while exporting the gridview? if this is the case please put the following code snippet :-

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
```

{
/* Verifies that the control is rendered */
}

**VerifyRenderingInServerForm** function is used to avoid the error like “**control must be placed in inside of form tag**”. If we set **VerifyRenderingInServerForm** function then compiler will think that controls rendered before exporting and functionality will work perfectly.

Hope this will work for you.

Thanks